# Print file path when rendering a partial in Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I manually add file paths to my partials so that it's easy for me to debug them. The code uses slim syntax:

#### In a partial

`= print_partial_dir 'admin/modules/_menu-left.html.slim'`

#### Application helper

`def print_partial_dir(path)
   "<!-- #{path} -->".html_safe if Rails.env.development?
 end`

Is there anyway so that when I render a partial in a view, I execute a filter or a hook so that the partial's file path is printed as a comment before the partial itself? Preferably, only do this when the rails environment is in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want debugging be eased by getting partial rendering information you can use `gem "xray-rails"`

```
group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
end
```

Then bundle and delete your cached assets:

```
$ bundle && rm -rf tmp/cache/assets
```

Restart your app, visit it in your browser, and press cmd+shift+x (Mac) or ctrl+shift+x to reveal the overlay ( [Documentation](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails))

In this way you can debug  all your partials when they are rendered.

Hope this Helps..

Comment: Thanks very much! The gem's perfect for what I want to do. :)